# Retrieving specific filename/ directory using information from a 2D array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, file, directory

I have a somewhat complicated `for` loop which fetches the names of certain files in a given directory.

My folder directory looks something like this:

---

`C:\xampp\htdocs\reports`

**Days**

```
2016-08-16
2016-08-17
2016-08-15
2016-08-14
2016-08-13
2016-08-12
...
```

---

And within each of those folders, there's subfolders:

**Reports**

```
01.43.19
03.43.19
05.43.20
07.43.20
...
```

---

Each of these subfolders contain a `.json` file with a directory similar to this:

**Report File**

`reports/2016-08-17/05.43.20/Default Report Name2016-08-17.json`

---

I'm trying to write a `for` loop, or a series of `for` loops which retrieve the amount of **`days`**, **`reports`** and **`report files`** all of which created dynamically as I will not know how many folders will exist in my final product.

Here is what I have so far: ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b90b31287d0238637c240017f78ebcd1)).

```
<?php

    //get days and add them to day[this][]
    if ($handle = opendir('C:\xampp\htdocs\reports')) 
    {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
            { 
                $day[][] = $file; // two D day - $day[x][y] - all days stored in X! 
            }
        }

        $day = array_reverse($day); // reverse to give the latest day first
    }

    //get reports and add them to day[][this]
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($day[0]) && $j < 5; $j++) // only get the reports for the latest 5 days (if there are more than 5 folders)
    {
        if ($handle1 = opendir("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\reports\\". $day[$j][0] . "\\"))
        {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle1))) 
            {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
                { 
                    $day[$j][] = $file;
                }
            }

            // just to test results
            for ($k = 1; $k < count($day[$j]); $k++) // start at 1 as we don't want to count the actual 'day' files
            {
                echo "<br> Report: " . $day[$j][$k];
            }

        }

        $jsonFilesArray[][] = array();

        for ($i = 1; $i < count($day[1]); $i++)
        {
            foreach (glob("reports/".$day[$j][0]."//" . $day[$j][$i] . "//*.json") as $jsonFile)
            {   
                $jsonFilesArray[$i][] = $jsonFile;
            }   
        }

        echo "<br> This is the count: " . count($jsonFilesArray);
        echo "<br> This is the report: " . $jsonFilesArray[0][0]; // should output something like: reports/2016-08-17/05.43.20/Default Report Name2016-08-17.json

    }
?>
```

The problem I'm having is retrieving the `.json` files/ directory which would look something like **this:**

`reports/2016-08-17/05.43.20/Default Report Name2016-08-17.json`

Instead I'm getting the **following:**

> Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\getStuff.php on
>   line 49

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong? And a way to get the desired output of : `reports/2016-08-17/05.43.20/Default Report Name2016-08-17.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`symfony/finder`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) component, which will simplify your code a lot. You *should* be able to do something like that with code like this (after some tweaking)

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$finder = new Finder();
$finder->name('*.json');
foreach ($finder->in('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\reports\\*\\*\\') as $file) {
    // ... do something with the file
}
```